# Error in token, nonetype has no attribute strip in module

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Code was working fine one minute, then I change something that should be harmless and it breaks. I revert it back to the **same** as it was when it was working, and get this error *(username censored)*:
[image: Error Message]

I used

```
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
```

to get the token. It does import the dotenv module, and the file is there with the proper info. Looks like this:

```
DISCORD_TOKEN='The Token'
DISCORD_GUILD='Server Name'
```

Comment: Please extract and provide a [mcve]. Also, make sure you read a bit what this error means and what can cause it. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: That's what I'm asking. What causes this error? Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: What @UlrichEckhardt is trying to ask is for you to provide the code that causes the error. It looks as though you have a `TOKEN` variable, but we won't know what's causing the error if we don't know what the variable contains. Could you please edit your question with all the necessary code that defines the token. (Of course also removing/replacing your actual token where necessary). For example, are you trying to read it from a file? Does that file exist? etc

Comment: "reproducible" -- the code you provide doesn't reproduce anything, it causes different errors than the ones you quote. You need to extract a reproducible example from your code. Nobody here should have to guess anything from your code, not even `import` statement. Instead, it should be possible to take the code from your question and run it. BTW: Don't post images of text, post the actual error text instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I found the answer some where else. Turns out the .env was failing somewhere and never got the token. I just removed it an had it read from another python file instead. Here's some up votes. https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/f4pk3e/trouble_with_making_a_discord_bot_with_pyhton/

Answer (score 0):

This is because `os.getenv` is returning None which means that your environment variables are not being set correctly.

If you are using dotenv, make sure you are actually loading the `.env` file with

```
dotenv.load_dotenv("path/to/your/.env")
```